# Assign a Value based on the numbers in a separate columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

So I *kind of* already know the possible solution but I don't know how to exactly go about it so please give me a bit of grace here.

I have a dataset for [youtube trends](https://www.kaggle.com/rsrishav/youtube-trending-video-dataset?select=US_youtube_trending_data.csv) that I want to read the values from two columns (likes and dislikes) and based off their contents I want an entry to be made in the new column. If the likes are higher than the dislikes I want it to be said as a 'positive' video and if it has more dislikes it should be 'negative'.

I'm primarily not sure how to go about this since most of the previous asks are based off of one column rather than two. I know some mentioned using cut, but would it still work the same?

all help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `df$new_col <- ifelse(df$likes > df$dislikes, 'positive', 'negative')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `ifelse` :

```
df$new_col <- ifelse(df$likes > df$dislikes, 'positive', 'negative')
```

This can also be written without `ifelse` as :

```
df$new_col <- c('negative', 'positive')[as.integer(df$likes > df$dislikes) + 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Vectorize` to create a vectorized version of a function. `vfunc <- Vectorize(func)` will allow you to call `df$newcol <- vfunc(df$likes, df$dislikes)` if your function takes two arguments and then return the result for each row in a vector that's assigned to a new column.